Confusion regarding Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Theorem 4 (Cayley-Hamilton). Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ . If $f$ is the characteristic polynomial for $T$ , then $\mathrm{f}(\mathrm{T})=0$; in other words, the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial for $T$.

I am currently reading Hoffman and Kunze's book, and this theorem confuses me because its statement seems to be a corollary of the previous theorem:

Theorem 3. Let $T$ be a linear operator on an $n$ -dimensional vector space $V$ [or, let $A$ be an $\mathrm{n} \times \mathrm{n}$ matrix $]$. The characteristic and minimal polynomials for $\mathrm{T}[$ for A] have the same roots, except for multiplicities. What we want to show is that $\boldsymbol{p}(c)=0$ if and only if $c$ is a characteristic value of $T$.

The fact that the minimal polynomial divides $f$ can be concluded from the definition of minimal polynomial and the fact that $f$ and the minimal polynomial have the same roots. So, what is the benefit of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem that Theorem 3 doesn't already provide? Did I misunderstand something?

Theorem 3 does not say anything about the multiplicities, so you cannot conclude that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial. For example $(x-1)^2(x+1)$ and $(x-1)(x+1)^2$ have the same roots but none of them divides the other.

@Gribouillis Can a minimal polynomial have multiplicities? It won't be minimal  anymore if it had it.

@Gribouillis Did I misunderstand  the concept of minimal polynomial?

Yes I think you misunderstood the concept of minimal polynomial. The minimal polynomial is the generator of the ideal of polynomials $f$ such that $f(T)=0$. For example the minimal polynomial of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\cr 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is $X^2$, which has a multiplicity.

Wikipedia has a good explanation of why even the minimal polynomial can have repeated roots. It's all to do with kernel nesting.

I have studied a "Cayley - hamilton theorem" like any square matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation... Is that the same theorem, everyone are discussing about ?

@Gribouillis This contradicts the proof of theorem 2 :Proof. Let $p$ be the minimal polynomial for $T$. Let $c$ be a scalar. What we want to show is that $\boldsymbol{p}(c)=0$ if and only if $c$ is a characteristic value of $T$.
First, suppose $p(c)=0$. Then
$$
p=(x-c) q
$$
where $q$ is a polynomial. Since $\operatorname{deg} q<\operatorname{deg} p$, the definition of the minimal polynomial $p$ tells us that $q(T) \neq 0$. Choose a vector $\beta$ such that $q(T) \beta \neq 0$. Let $\alpha=q(T) \beta$.

@One Your proof does not say $q(c)\not = 0$, it says $q(T)\not = 0$

@Gribouillis Sorry I meant $T$, I still don't understand why $(x-c)$ have no multiplicity.

This imply that any minimal polynomial have no multiplicity.

@One the proof does not say that $(x-c)$ has no multiplicity. In the example of the matrix that I wrote above, you have $p = x^2$ and $q = x$. One can choose $\beta = \begin{pmatrix}0\cr 1\end{pmatrix}$.
